# How to get devicess connected to a wifi router from android?

Tags: android, linux, network-programming, android-wifi

I recently came across an application called Wifi Analyzer for android. This application lists the devices present in an network. **Does any one know how to get the mac of devices connected to a wifi router(to which my android device is connected) using android application?** I am developing an application to measure the performance of wifi router. **How can measure the speed of wifi router(the actual speed)?** Please help. 
[image])

Comment: To answer part of your question, to test the speed of a router you can transfer a file to a given location on the intranet (could be the phone itself), time how long the transfer takes, and then divide the file size by that time. There are certainly more sophisticated ways to do this, but as long as you use a reasonably large file this will garner a solid measurement.

Comment: @DrJPepper Thank you for the quick replay.... I thought in your way, but this large file has to be a part of application write??? wouldn't that make the application of huge size?? is there any way to without sending the file??

Comment: You could just programmatically generate a dummy file of all 0's or something similar. You could also stream characters over the network if RAM is tight.

Comment: @DrJPepper I try that....Do you have any idea on the first Question??

Comment: Not off the top of my head, sorry. There are tons of FOSS programs that can retrieve MAC's though, maybe ask one of those communities on IRC, or perhaps look through the source code of nmap if you're feeling adventurous.